# document.write (trouble with syntax adding a href)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been having trouble getting the correct string formatted for my document.write()function. Any help is greatly appreciated. Jsfiddle link below of what i have so far. Below is what I am trying to achieve.
[jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrazySpatial/Zt5Z2/9/)

```
<a href="https://web.fulcrumapp.com/api/v2/photos/ + myarray[i] +.jpg?token=3c04f586f4991a" target="_blank"><img style="height:100px;" src="https://web.fulcrumapp.com/api/v2/photos/+ myarray[i]+.jpg?token=3c04f586f4991a" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Fiddle code is currently putting the link text inside the link tag itself. You should close the `>` before putting the link text ;)

Additionally, don't use `document.write`...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Niet for the advice I am looking into how to do this another way, but for now I was able to figure out my syntax.

```
 document.write("<li><a href=\"" + url + "" + myarray[i] + "" + token + "\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"" + url + "" + myarray[i] + "\"></a></li>");
```